# How to display a custom message before the shipping methods load?

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, shipping-methods

I want to display a custom message before the shipping methods load and hide that message after shipping methods loading done. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you need custom message already available at checkout and hide it when shipping methods load OR it would be shown when shipping methods load triggered and hidden after load?

Comment: @HimmatPaliwal Yes i want to display custom message when shipping methods loading like "Please wait shipping methods loading" and hide that message after loading done

Answer (score 0):

You can play with

> Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service.js
>
> Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping.js
>
> /Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method.js

These js files triggers when shipping methods loaded.

**Update:**

Please override below file in your custom theme

> /Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method.js

and add below code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    '../model/quote'
], function ($, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (shippingMethod) {
        $('.msg-wrapper').show();
        quote.shippingMethod(shippingMethod);
        $('.msg-wrapper').hide();
    };
});
```

You have to create a container with class "msg-wrapper" having the required message to show while methods loading. It would be shown when method loads and hidden once loaded.

To test the above, you can add simple alert by using below code in

> app/design/frontend/package/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/select-shipping-method.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    '../model/quote'
], function ($, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (shippingMethod) {
        alert('Please wait shipping methods loading');
        quote.shippingMethod(shippingMethod);
        alert('Shipping methods loaded');
    };
});
```